# Makefile: Executing builtin function passed as a parameter to call

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm writing the following Makefile:

```
CHECK = $($1 $2)
$(info $(call CHECK,dir,a/b/c))

stop:
```

and executing it in GNU Make 4.3 as `make` without args. What I expect in output is `a/b/` but I get empty line instead.

My actual question is how may I pass/get/use builtin functions in other macros to make those passed functions work? Is this possible?

*Note:* Actual Makefile is slightly more complex, but this short example demonstrates the idea. I know I may just write `$(dir a/b/c)` but this is not what I want.

**UPD:** My actual use case is the following. I have a list of files processed in pipeline of template (having `%`) rules. Some of those files have spaces in their names and in order to get their names interpreted correctly I use the following trick:

```
ESCAPE_IN_SHELL = sed -E 's,_,_1,g;s, ,_2,g'
ESCAPE = $(subst $() ,_2,$(subst _,_1,$1))
UNESCAPE = $(subst _1,_,$(subst _2, ,$1))
MAP = $(foreach A,$2,$(call $1,$A))

# Names acquisition
NAMES != ls in_dir | ${ESCAPE_IN_SHELL}

trans_dir/% : in_dir/%
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    ...

out_dir/% : trans_dir/%
    ...

main_rule : $(call MAP,UNESCAPE,${NAMES})
```

The problem is in that `mkdir -p $(dir $@)` precisely in how `$@` is interpreted by `$(dir ...)` when it contains spaces. What I do to fix this is replacing `$(dir $@)` with
`$(call UNESCAPE,$(dir $(call ESCAPE,$@)))`

But I've found that it is possible to generalize and shorten solution by creating additional function like this:

```
SAFE = $(call UNESCAPE,$($1 $(call ESCAPE,$2)))
```

It should be used like `$(call SAFE,dir,$@)`. And here I faced the problem that `dir` doesn't get expanded as expected.

Comment: This seems quite convoluted, but you appear to be looking for `$(eval ...)`

Comment: @tripleee, could you provide an example for this case using `eval`?

Comment: `$(eval $$(info $$(dir a/b/c)))` does what you ask but it's unlikely to be directly useful. Probably [edit] your question to demonstrate a case where this is actually useful so we can see some more context.

Comment: @tripleee, I've just found it too, thank you! It does exactly what I need!

Comment: @tripleee, Uhh, looks like `$(eval $$(info $$(dir a/b/c)))` puts the result of `$(dir a/b/c)` to make's process stdout, but not in the "evaluation context". So it looked like it's working only while I was writing it to stdout myself, not consuming it further

Comment: Yeah, exactly; your original example simply wasn't very useful. Thanks for the edit; this looks more relevant now. But spaces in `Makefile` dependencies is really just something you'd want to work around by other means. Perhaps you could symlink to names which don't have spaces?

Comment: Of course I may solve the problem with spaces more gracefully, but I don't see the reason, why initial `CHECK` function don't work. It is not obvious from GNU Make documentation and for me it looks like a bug

Comment: It's not a bug.  You can't call a function whose name is contained in a variable; that's just not how expansion works.  As in my answer, you have to use `call` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't read all the details of the issue but if documentation for the `call` function is pretty clear about this:

> If variable is the name of a built-in function, the built-in function is always invoked (even if a make variable by that name also exists).

So if you want to call a function, including a built-in function, you can't use:

```
CHECK = $($1 $2)
```

you have to use:

```
CHECK = $(call $1,$2)
```